# Firefox won't change image source

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

I'm trying to change an image in JavaScript+Prototype by changing the "src" attribute of the element. It works fine in IE, but not in Firefox. I don't get any errors and the script continues executing after this bit executes:

```
var image = $('toggle');
image.setAttribute("src", "../images/icons/icon_minus.gif");
image.setAttribute("alt", "Minus Symbol");
image.setAttribute("title", "Collapse tree");
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I make the browser replace the existing image "icon_plus.gif" with "icon_minus.gif"? I'm sure it must be something really obvious but I can't figure out what!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant figure out what is wrong, but I believe its possible to do a:

```
image.src = "../images/icons/icon_minus.gif";
```

BTW, is the image path absolutely correct?

Comment: I created a test Prototype script using the code you posted; it worked perfectly in FireFox. It is possible that FireFox wasn't able to fetch the image when you tested... network problem or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This function works fine in all browsers(chrome,Firefox,IE,Edge,...):

```
function recaptcha() {
  $("#captcha-img").attr('src', "");
  setTimeout(function(){
       $("#captcha-img").attr('src', "captcha?"+new Date().getTime());
  }, 0);
 }
```

The important point is generating new URL which forces FF and IE to re-render the image.