# Force firefox to reload image after img.src change

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas

I'm modifying some images on canvas and then setting src of this images to new base64 coded pictures.

```
img.src = changeColor(img);
```

changeColor returns base64 coded image:

```
return canvas.toDataURL();
```

Chrome and Opera are refreshing images after src change, but firefox don't!
I also inspected the image element by FireBug, and it shows new src and new image!

I have already tried to add Data to URL but uhh... this is a base64 coded image, not an url, so it breaks my pictures totally.

I there any way to force reload images or disable firefox cache via javascript?

UPDATE:
I have also tried to set image.src=''; in changeColor function.
It works in chrome, but in firefox... picture disappear, and do not appear again when i set new base64 value.

Comment: Can't really help without seeing the relevant code to understand the options.

Comment: If it is a base64 coded image it can't be a cache problem, because if the image changes the base64 data will change. Or am I missing something? Maybe removing and adding the image dom element again is something you could try. (or set the src to "" and then to your actual data, don't know if that helps, but it's worth a try)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox won't change image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826799/firefox-wont-change-image-source)

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me as @dmmd mentioned. You only need to add query string with a random value.

```
id.src = "path?t=t"+ Math.random(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not using image data, but this worked for a similar issue where FF was not reloading when the src variable didn't change:

```
image.src = "";
setTimeout(function(){
    image.src = //the new image src
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the image format (and use jpg). It may re-encode the image:

```
return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
```

Comment: It's working correctly on most browsers, but in firefox don't.

Comment: Try to add a "?" (query string sign) at the end of your src. Not sure if it would help in this case, but I remember that it saved me once when I had a similar issue with FF.

Comment: I have tried... "?" breaks image data. It's because src IS image data, not a standard URL.